# devise: cannot login if I have a user controller with a show method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using Devise on a Rails 3 project and I'm trying to do all this with BDD using Cucumber and Rspec.

The problem is when I go to login using a Cucumber Scenario like so:

```
  Scenario: Login
    Given I am not authenticated
    And I am on the home page
    And I have a user with username "jsmith"
    When I follow "Log in"
    And I fill in "Username" with "jsmith"
    And I fill in "Password" with "password"
    And I press "Sign in"
    Then I should be on the home page
    And I should see "Logged in successfully."
    And I should see "Log out"
```

I run into a problem when I've got the following in my routes.rb

```
  match 'home' => "home#index"

  devise_for :users,
  :path_names => { :sign_in => 'login', :sign_out => 'logout'}

  devise_scope :user do
    get '/login' => 'devise/sessions#create'
    get '/logout' => 'devise/sessions#destroy'
  end

  resources :users
```

The problem is I don't see "Logged in successfully". If however I change the line in my routes.rb to

```
resources :users, :except => [:show]
```

Then it works fine, but I cannot have a show method for user then.

Is there a way around all this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is the problem that you don't see the "logged in successfully" or is it that you're not logged in? I'm thinking that devise redirects to your user, if it doesn't find it goes to another page... index? - do you have the notice tag and snippet in your show page (that should be in the layout)?

**EDIT**

You should check if you have the session value in your show, do accomplish that put `<%= session.to_yaml %>` in your show, if you don't see the string 'Signed in' my guess is that it has been deleted, probably because you've been redirected.

Comment: The problem is I don't see the notice message if I remove the 'except => [:show]' in my routes.rb file. 
I do have a flash[:notice] in my layout file and I do see messages.
I really just want to have a show user page if possible when using Devise.

Comment: I'd like to know if you have the flash param in your session in users#show. If you do I'd like to see your views, show, index and layout

Comment: I have a flash param in my application layout. I don't have anything in my show view yet.